# Why use __init__ and self when we can use simple methods

Tags: class, methods, python-3.7, init, self

I am having confusion as to why do we use **init** and self while defining a class when we can use methods. The following example illustrates my confusion:

Example 1 Utilizing **init** and self:

```
class car:
    def __init__(self,model,color):
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
    def show(self):
        print('model is', self.model)
        print('color is', self.color)    

audi = car('audi a4', 'blue')
ferrari = car('ferrari 488','green')

audi.show()
model is audi a4
color is blue

ferrari.show()
model is ferrari 488
color is green
```

Example 2 Utilizing methods:

```
class car:
    def audifeatures(car, model, color):
        print ('car is', car, 'model is', model, 'color is', color)
    def ferrarifeatures(car, model, color):
        print ('car is', car, 'model is', model, 'color is', color)

car.audifeatures('audi','x8','black')
car is audi model is x8 color is black

car.ferrarifeatures('ferrari','f5','red')
car is ferrari model is f5 color is red
```

Comment: `car.audifeatures('ferrari','f5','red')` will still give you the Ferrari description.

Comment: and you won't have *instances* of cars. you just have a static class with some static methods.

Comment: this would be a good primer: https://www.python-course.eu/classes_and_type.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "car is audi model is x8 color is black" generated by your `print` statement is just *words*; you're simply forming a string that uses the *words* "model" and "color" (and the `car` class is basically irrelevant).

`init` and `self` is about defining an *object with properties* so that you can do object-based programming; the `car` class generates an *instance* that actually *has* a model and a color.

It's like the difference between a parrot that repeats the phrase "I am six feet tall" and a human being who actually *is* six feet tall.